# How to implement bare metal recovery for windows server os in c++

Tags: c++, winpe, volume-shadow-service

I tried to implement bare metal recovery for windows os machine. I thought of implementing it using VolumeShadowService (VSS). Till now I am able to take backup of entire system using vss and backupread and write functions and also completed restore using windows pe. Booting into PE, I run my restore application in such a way that, all volumes are formatted and files are restored (including system reserved partition). But after I restart the machine, It is showing the following error "***The file is possibly corrupt. The file header checksum does not match the computed checksum***" Please help to solve this. Thanks in advance.